# php server to server push communication

Tags: php, web-services, sockets, server-push

i have 2 servers (A,B) so far B is pulling A for information. Now i am looking for possibilites to push information from A to B.

The push could be over "fire and forget" as B will still be pulling from time to time.

The simplest solution i could think of would be w webservice over HTTP posting information from A to B. Are there any other valid (php) solutions?

How about a socket connection? is this a valid approach for php?
Or switching from HTTP to UDP (less overhead?)

Are there any benchmarks you know of?

Thx for your time and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming pure PHP:

HTTP POSTing is the simplest solution in my mind.

With a socket connection, unless you have a socket listening indefinitely on B (I wouldn't even consider this), you'll need A to POST B to set up a socket anyway.

I think there is probably some benefit to the socket connection if you're transferring large amounts of data, but if not I'd stick to the POST.

Comment: thx for your quick response. Could you explain or point me to some information why "listening indefinitely" is a bad idea? And how about other protocols then HTTP?

Comment: I think I had my web-head on at the time. In terms of running PHP as an Apache module it is inefficient to keep a thread tied up listening. Running it as CLI negates this though, and assuming the frequency of data is high enough to make it more efficient to leave the socket open than to open/close each time, then this seems sensible. Think about who else could connect to your server / what damage could they do if a port is left open indefinitely?

Comment: In terms of TCP/UDP, this depends on the importance of your data arriving (okay, if B is still polling as in your post then this is low - although I do't see why you'd bother with both PUSHing and polling) and whether the benefits (lower overhead) of UDP are worthwhile (depending on frequency and size of data).